# What is the best and optimal way to return multiple anonymous type lists in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generic-list

I have 3 lists which are of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: System.DateTime.Week, int Count>>.`

In my program I'm using list of Type (let's say detailsList) which contains data fetched from DB.

Using this detailsList I'm creating 3 separate lists which are of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: System.DateTime.Week, int Count>>.`

Basically the Select part for these lists is as follows :

```
detailsList
    .Where(where_part)
    .Select(x => x.Week)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Week)
    .(x => new { Week = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

How can I return these lists from a method by using the most optimal way?
What would be the return type for this method in this case?

**NOTE : After being returned I want to individually access these lists again as I need to fill 3 different data table susing these lists.**

Comment: The best answer is just *not* to use an anonymous type. In C# 7 - within an application at least - I'd use a tuple type. Is that an option for you?

Comment: you can use object type

Comment: How do you build these lists? How do you intend to use the lists once they are returned?

Comment: Anonymous types are just a convenience. The compiler creates the type for you so you avoid to do it explicitly yourself. However, these types cannot be used as function return types (or function arguments). If you want to return a specific type from a function you cannot use an anonymous type. C# 7 value tuples gives you some of the convenience of an anonymous type because you don't have to specify the type somewhere else. It's specified right there in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: the first part of this answer is for C#6. If using C#7 you could use C#7's built-in tuple return type as described at the end.

---

Your code:

```
detailsList.Where(where_part).Select(x=>x.Week).GroupBy(x=>x.Week).Select(x=>x.Count)
```

...does not select an anonymous type. That will return an `IEnumerable<int>`. If you wanted a list of week/count pairs, you'd need to do:

```
detailsList.Where(where_part).Select(x=>x.Week).GroupBy(x=>x.Week)
   .Select(x=>new {Week = x.Key, x.Count()})
```

Anyway, if I understand the question, you want to return three lists, such as (making up an example):

1. number of cakes baked per week
2. number of cakes sold per week
3. number of cakes burnt per week

...where each element in the lists looks something like `{Week: 3, Count: 22}`.

You could use a `Tuple` to store the week/count pairs. There's no *type* `System.DateTime.Week`, it's just an `int`, so a suitable `Tuple` would be `Tuple<int, int>`. And so you'd be returning several `List`s of those (or `IList`, `ICollection` or even `IEnumerable`s).

[It strikes me that you might be going to use those lists to look up the "count" for a given "week" - in which case, it might be more convenient to create a `Dictionary<int, int>` rather than a `List` of `Tuple<int, int>`s. In that case, you could replace the last `Select` with a `ToDictionary()` call.]

Anyway, you now have the problem of how to return *three* of these lists (or dictionaries) from your method. You have several options:

1. Don't. Create three methods :-)
2. Return an object that aggregates the lists (an array, another list, another tuple, or even your own type).
3. Use 3 "out" parameters.

Whichever you choose, using a `Tuple` type would allow you to declare the type of the return value / out parameters relatively easily. Personally, I'd probably create my own return type such as:

```
class CakeInfo
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> CakesBakedByWeek { get; private set; }
    List<Tuple<int, int>> CakesSoldByWeek { get; private set; }
    List<Tuple<int, int>> CakesBurntByWeek { get; private set; }

    public CakeInfo(
        IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> baked, 
        IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> sold, 
        IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> burnt
    )
    {
        CakesBakedByWeek = baked.ToList();
        CakesSolByWeek = sold.ToList();
        CakesBurntByWeek = burnt.ToList();
    } 
}
```

...except that I'd never just use a `List` :-)  ... in this case I'd either use `IReadOnlyCollection<Tuple<int, int>>` or `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int>`.

To use this, your `GetCakeInfo` method might look something like:

```
public CakeInfo GetCakeInfo()
{
    var detailsList = ...;

    var baked = detailsList.Where(where_part_baked).Select(x=>x.Week).GroupBy(x=>x.Week)
       .Select(x=>new Tuple<int, int>(x.Key, x.Count()));

    var sold = detailsList.Where(where_part_sold).Select(x=>x.Week).GroupBy(x=>x.Week)
       .Select(x=>new Tuple<int, int>(x.Key, x.Count()));

    var burnt = detailsList.Where(where_part_burnt).Select(x=>x.Week).GroupBy(x=>x.Week)
       .Select(x=>new Tuple<int, int>(x.Key, x.Count()));

    return new CakeInfo(baked, sold, burnt);
}
```

(Of course, you could have a helper method to factor out the repeated code above).

---

**C#7**

If you were using C#7, then you could more easily return all three lists as the return value from the method by using a tuple return type such as:

```
public (
    List<Tuple<int, int>> baked,
    List<Tuple<int, int>> sold,
    List<Tuple<int, int>> burnt
) GetCakeInfo()
{
    ...
    return (baked, sold, burnt);
}
```

You'd call this like so:

```
(List<Tuple<int, int>> baked, List<Tuple<int, int>> sold, List<Tuple<int, int>> burnt) = GetCakeInfo();
```

...or...

```
var cakeLists = GetCakeInfo();
var baked = cakeLists.baked;
// ...
```

What's more, you could use the new `ValueTuple` type rather than the old `Tuple` type for the list elements. So:

```
public (
    List<(int week, int count)> baked,
    List<(int week, int count)> sold,
    List<(int week, int count)> burnt
) GetCakeInfo()
{
    ...
    return (baked, sold, burnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can create a View Model which matches with your output and use that to create `System.Collections.Generic.List<YourViewModel>` . Then you can return that.